# Electrostatic force setup not working

Tags: electrostatics

[image]

I am using a glass rod and a polythene bag for a demonstration on electrostatic force. The setup was working perfectly fine yesterday night and I could attract small pieces of paper and I verified it using a homemade electroscope too. Today though, it's not working. It's a sunny day and I am going through the same procedure and nothing works. Could someone troubleshoot my problem please?

Comment: More information is needed:  Are you using the same bag or just a similar one?  Are you using the same paper? What is your procedure?

Comment: Yep the same exact bag and the same exact paper from the same exact notebook and the same exact electroscope. I take my glass rod and rub it gently against the bag, as if you were cleaning a pipe with a cloth.

Comment: I think it might be due to the temperature, it's about 40°C here at daytime and 25°C at night.

Comment: Relative humidity is strongly affected by temperature.  If the relative humidity is high, elactrostatic charges dissipate quickly.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try the experiment at night and report back.

Comment: You might consider using a hair dryer GENTLY to warm all the objects you are using, so as to drive off moisture from their surfaces. But do be very cautious or you could end up with shrivelled plastic – or worse.

Comment: You might also try measuring the relative humidity using a hygrometer, during several different sessions.

Comment: Well I tried it now that it's night. The temperature is 29°C and the relative humidity is 30%. The same exact setup and it doesn't work.

Comment: I have been trying it at the best of condition I can, it just stopped working,  could you recommend some other materials? I have given up hope for these.